# how to put the different times in y axis in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

greeting for every one,

I have data in excel file  and i want to draw a plot in Matlab in which the Y axis represent the time with starting time in 10:45 for 24 hours i.e, from 10:00 am to the next day in 10:00 am. The x-axis represents the excel file data( the values of frequencies during 24 hours)

how to put the different times in the y axis showing the values of time in the formula of time(00:00 am/pm) using matlab?

if i use this code: `ylim(subplot2,[1 24])` and `xlim(subplot2,[170 230])` it will be plotted but the y-axis shows only the hours from 1 to 24 hours and i need the y-axis from 10:45 am(starting time) to(10:45)am in interval 24 hours

Comment: What have you got so far? Have you considered `hist`?

Comment: if i use this code:  ylim(subplot2,[1 24]) and (xlim(subplot2,[170 230]) it will be plotted but the y-axis shows only the hours from 1 to 24 hours and i need the y-axis from 10:45 am(starting time) to(10:45)am in interval 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom tick labels by specifying tick strings with the command:

```
time_cells = {'10:45','11:45',...,'9:45','10:45'};
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', time_cells)
```

Where `gca` is the handle of your current plot (axes), and the `time_cells` is a cell array containing all your required tick labels (without the ellipse). It is probably easiest to generate this using a for-loop to create the numbers you want, and then `num2str` to convert to the strings you need.